# How do I repackage a .deb for Ubuntu Snappy?

Tags: packaging, deb, ubuntu-core, snap

I want to convert some Ubuntu software in `.deb`, specifically [`guake`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/guake), to packages for Ubuntu Snappy*.

According to [the documentation on the Ubuntu dev tools](https://developer.ubuntu.com/snappy/build-apps/),

> All metadata lives in meta/package.yaml. The details of that file are documented in the snappy developer documentation, but in short, it's super simple and you can get away with something as straightforward as:
>
> ```
> name: pkgname  
> version: version-string  
> apps:  
>   binary:  
>    - command: path/to/binary  
>   another-binary  
>    - command: path/to/another-binary
> ```
>
> ... your package is called "pkgname" ... version "version-string" and ... binaries, called pkgname/name and pkgname/another.

I [googled it myself](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=How+do+I+repackage+a+.deb+for+Ubuntu+Snappy), and have found little on the subject of such conversion.

As a build engineer, by trade, and an Ubuntu enthusiast by love, I may be in a position to benefit from learning this sort of thing.

How does a .deb turn into snap*?

<sub>* Apparently, the format for packages for Ubuntu Snappy is called the "snap" format.</sub>

Comment: this might be a good thing to look at, haven't tried myself, but might help someone form an answer:  https://github.com/mikix/deb2snap

Comment: // , Actually, that seems like a pretty good answer.

Comment: deb2snap is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/blob/fd5d4a3a1e3f0acc13370adbf98c9a3481d1328a/leafpad/snapcraft.yaml for a simple example.

The relevant part of `snapcraft.yaml` here is:

`parts:
  leafpad:
    plugin: nil
    stage-packages: [leafpad]`

Here you define a part called `leafpad`, for which nothing needs to be done (`nil` plugin), but the contents of the Ubuntu package `leafpad` to be staged. That's it.

https://developer.ubuntu.com/snappy/build-apps/ obviously has more information on that.

Comment: // , It wasn't obvious to me. This attempt at an answer isn't too comprehensive, but I may be able to piece something together from the contents of the pages at those links. I no longer work on systems that use Ubuntu in production or development environments, but I am still somewhat curious.

Comment: This is not a good solution, debian packages are not only zipped files, they have scripts like preinst, postinst,prerm, porstrm...so on. They won't work without that.

Answer (score -1):

I found [deb2snap](https://github.com/mikix/deb2snap) which converts deb packages to snaps.

Haven't tried it.

Comment: It's not maintained anymore.

Comment: // , @dholbach, why do you say this? /\

Comment: Because Michael Terry is a colleague of mine and he's not working on deb2snap any more. The last commit was a year ago and snapd/snapcraft have moved on since then.