# snapcraft.yaml syntax for a pre-compiled binary

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I made a c++ web server that has dependencies. I usually get them from aptitude. The only way that I see to download and put them in a snap is to build a part and list them under "stage-packages".

My issue is the part requires a plugin and source, of which I don't think I need. Is there a way to pull the different dependencies on their own?

Comment: This is a bit of a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/635691/how-do-i-repackage-a-deb-for-ubuntu-snappy right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're not using Snapcraft to build your web server (remember it can run make, cmake, autotools, etc.)? Use the nil plugin, then-- it does nothing, but allows you to pull in stage-packages. For example:

```
name: foo
version: 1.0
vendor: me <me@me.com>
summary: My app summary
description: My app description
icon: icon.png

parts:
  bar:
    plugin: nil
    stage-packages:
      - my-system-dependency
```