# Is there an automatic conversion utility deb-to-snap?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-core, snap

I am looking for a script that automates the conversion of a Debian apt-package including dependencies to a snap package for ubuntu core/touch?

Comment: You should probably not convince your customer to do this at all. Why are you trying?

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad might be helpful if you explained why.

Comment: This is a bit of a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/635691/how-do-i-repackage-a-deb-for-ubuntu-snappy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script was a good one, however, it's aging and not supported anymore. The good news is that you have easier way now with snapcraft to do it!

Basically, you have snapcraft parts, and you can attach to them some `stage-packages` that will download your deb from the Ubuntu repo (ppa support is in progress). The resulting binary will be put in the snapcraft stage directoy.
I encourage you to have a look at this page (section "Adding an Ubuntu dependency to a part"): https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/your-first-snap/ where you can see that `fswebcam` is pulled from the upstream repository, and then, have a look at the snapcraft tutorial: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/get-started/

Comment: I suggest adding an example of using the nil plugin to pull in the .deb and make it available with the binaries/services. Also, a warning: pulling .debs with Snapcraft may not work the way you want, since Snapcraft simply unpacks them. Any .deb that makes use of postinst scripts etc. may not work very well, in which case it's time to actually repackage as a .snap.

Comment: Links are dead. (I'll keep looking. :)

Answer (score 1):

Test https://github.com/mikix/deb2snap script, seems pretty good. I'm not sure about future updates, though.

See also [How do I repackage a .deb for Ubuntu Snappy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635691/how-do-i-repackage-a-deb-for-ubuntu-snappy)